# how to use loop paste function(with "+" sign) in R

Tags: r

I'm creating a regression model and should use iterators. but i have some problem
I want to turn this code into a loop, but I do not know what to do.

In particular, I do not know how to do "+" and "," in the paste function in a loop. please help me

```
**R Code**

x <- array(1:(length(cor_test_table)-1))

if(length(cor_test_table)==nrow(Total)) 
{
  print("There are no independent variables that satisfy the correlation 
coefficient. Please adjust the correlation coefficient.")
}
if(1==length(cor_test_table)-1) # 1 independent variable
{
  lm_var <- paste(x[1]) 
}
if(2==length(cor_test_table)-1) # 2 independent variable
{
  lm_var <- paste(x[1],"+",x[2]) 
}  
if(3==length(cor_test_table)-1) # 3 independent variable
{
  lm_var <- paste(x[1],"+",x[2],"+",x[3]) 
}
if(4==length(cor_test_table)-1) # 4 independent variable
{
  lm_var <- paste(x[1],"+",x[2],"+",x[3],"+",x[4]) 
}else 
{
  print("There are too many independent variables, five or more. Please 
adjust the correlation coefficient.")
}
```

Comment: `lm_var <- paste(x, collapse = "+")`. Works with `x` of any length.

Comment: Thanks!! it is very simple but very effective~!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for this should go to Rui Barradas but he's not put it as an answer.

The formula can be produced using `as.formula(response ~ paste(x, collapse = " + "))` 
where x is a character vector of terms to include.

Note you can also specify the formula *exclusively* rather than *inclusively* as follows

```
data(mtcars)

summary(lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)) #regresses mpg on all other variables
summary(lm(mpg ~ . - gear, data = mtcars)) # regresses mpg on all other variables EXCEPT gear
```

And so on.